# Multiple Hyper links in a same cell in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on a `SSRS report` which have hyperlinks to `CRM` sytem. I need to implement a logic where a single textbox will have `multiple CRM links`. I have implemented a logic as below

```
=(join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(lookupset(Fields!Deal.Value ,Fields!Deal.Value ,
"<a href = " & Chr(34) & iif(isnothing(Parameters!CRM_URL.Value), Nothing,
Parameters!CRM_URL.Value & "?ID={" &
Fields!ID.Value
 & "}&LogicalName=gc_deal") & Chr(34) 
& ">" & Fields!Concatinatedvalues.Value & "</a>","dataset1")),"<br>"))
```

> Note : `Fields!Concatinatedvalues.Value` coming as comma separated strings. for eg: "`link1,link2,link3`".

With the above logic Hyperlinks are working only for single strings. For comma separated strings its not working. I tried to modify the code as below

```
=(join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(lookupset(Fields!Deal.Value ,Fields!Deal.Value , "<a href = " & Chr(34) & iif(isnothing(Parameters!CRM_URL.Value), Nothing, Parameters!CRM_URL.Value & "?ID={" & split(Fields!ID.Value,",").GetValue(0)  & "}&LogicalName=gc_deal") & Chr(34)  & ">" & Fields!Concatinatedvalues.Value & "</a>","dataset1")),"<br>"))
```

With the above logic only the link for `first string` is working. Other string links are not working. Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: no answer yet,means there is problem in your explanation.First try to explain with plain english.What do you mean by multiple href in same textbox ?how it will apear ?what is your input like ?

Comment: I would guess you have a problem with the order of the functions and you would need to split the Concatinatedvalues into the three urls and then run the lookupset on them individually, then join them back together. So you would come out with 3 clickable links that would then be comma separated.

Comment: So, what would be the relation between `Fields!ID.Value` and `Fields!Concatinatedvalues.Value`?  It seems to me that you may have something like `ID={53116537-f993-4538-bbb4-1216b9eba0ea} -> Concatinatedvalues="string1,string2,string3"`. Is that so?

Comment: i have fixed it by adding a sub report and move this concatenation  logic to it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a sub report and moved the concatenation logic to it.